# Excluding header rows from column declaration insertion using the array package

Tags: formatting, longtable, columns

I am using the `<{decl.}` option provided by the `array` package in order to append a currency symbol to each value in a specific column, in a custom `longtable` environment. I can't however figure out how to exclude the header rows from the declaration insertion (note the symbol "€" in the title of the last column).

I am compiling with **XeLaTeX**.
Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

% Custom environment
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red!60!black}{#1}}}
\newenvironment{customtabular}[5]{%
    \begin{longtable}{@{} l l p{.45\linewidth} c r<{\hfill €} @{}}
        \rowcolor{green!10}
        \head{#1} & \head{#2} & \head{#3} & \head{#4} & \head{#5}\\
        \endfirsthead
        \rowcolor{green!10}
        \head{#1} & \head{#2} & \head{#3} & \head{#4} & \head{#5}\\
        \endhead
    }%
    {\end{longtable}
}

% Table contents
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,60}{\xappto\mytablecontents{\i & value & value & value & num \\}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{customtabular}{column1}{column2}{column3}{column4}{column5}
        \mytablecontents
    \end{customtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrayPackage]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn{1}` to provide a different column specification, perhaps most easily do it for all your headings

```
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textcolor{red!60!black}{#1}}}}
```

or leave the original definition and just do

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{column 5}}
```

when needed.